# RDP access of GCP window server through GCp console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance

Can we establish RDP access to Windows Server provided by Cloud Platform (GCP) through GCP console without assigning an external IP address to that server?
Can you get RDP access to server through GCP serial console instead of the web based terminal window?

Comment: you need RDP client to connect to GCP window.  In GCP console there is no RDP client is installed

Comment: The Google Cloud Console does not yet provide RDP. You can set up an IAP tunnel using the CLI `gcloud` and then RDP (third-part tool) to instances with only a private IP address. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding

Comment: Explain what GCP stands for.  Added better context for the console window.

Answer (score 2):

You launched the instances without external IP addresses. Therefore, those instances aren't directly addressable on the internet. In order to establish a Remote Desktop connection, you can use Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) for TCP Forwarding to create a secure tunnel between a local port and the Remote Desktop port, 3389, on the target instance. Using Cloud IAP for TCP Forwarding allows secure administrative connections without exposing your instances to the internet.

Install gcloud-sdk in your local machine. and run *gcloud init*

To enable port forwarding between a local port over a secure tunnel to a target instance and port in GCP, you use the start-iap-tunnel command, which has the following syntax:
*gcloud beta compute start-iap-tunnel instance-name instance-port --zone=zone \
--project=project-id*

once this is done you can see
Testing if tunnel connection works.
Listening on port [53389].
the port may not be 53389 in your case

Set windows password

Using your Remote Desktop client of choice, connect to the instance by specifying localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the remote address and 53389(or your port) as the remote port.
When you're prompted, enter the username and password you created for windows machine

Answer (score 0):

there's a crhome extension named [Chrome RDP for Google Cloud Platform](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-rdp-for-google-clo/mpbbnannobiobpnfblimoapbephgifkm).

with this extension installed, when opening your vm settings you will see a RDP button

[image]

just hit it and you will be directly prompted to enter your credentials to login

[image]